# Bootstrap - how to keep list items contents with quick floats to one line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing the following issue - when I add a glyphicon with a pull-right class to a li option it looks ok as long as the text within li isn't too long. If it is, the glyphicon gets pushed slightly below the text (to a next line I guess).
How can I make it stay in the same line?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group open">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle">Input <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a id="1" class="cursor-hand">Very long text here<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-danger pull-right"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="2" class="cursor-hand">Empty option</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="41" class="cursor-hand">Short<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-danger pull-right"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

One more thing that is very annoying is this happens all the time in FF 30.0 (running Win XP here) while Chrome and IE (tested in 8.0) at least try to keep the text and the icon in line.

Here's a fiddle that shows the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ukgAY/

Comment: I do not see the problem. The three checkmarks are lined up well; http://www.bootply.com/WFKxewqfKW

Comment: @JordanD you can see it if you resize the window

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the pull-right and position the tickbox manually : I replaced the pull-right with pright class

```
ul li a  {position: relative }
.pright {position: absolute; right: 0;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3JgND/

Comment: This also makes the icon move vertically.

Comment: then move it back - top: 3px or whatever! I've given you an additional way of positioning the tickbox.

Comment: adding `padding-top: 3px;` fixes it

Comment: thank you. but is there any way I could preserve padding on the right side as well? there is 20px padding before the text, I'd like it to look like:
<20px>Text<justified to right>icon<20px>
Adding 'padding-right' has an undesired effect of icon landing on top of the text

Comment: I'd set the position with right:0 - you could use right: 30px but that will almost certainly overlap. You'd then need to decide how to resolve that - perhaps make the menu wider with .dropdown-menu > li > a {width: 215px;} for instance